# Can't install PyQt5 versions older than 5.14 through pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've tried to use "pip install pyqt5==5.13" but am getting the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5==5.13 (from versions: 5.14.0, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, 5.15.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.2, 5.15.3, 5.15.4, 5.15.5, 5.15.6, 5.15.7, 5.15.8, 5.15.9, 5.15.10)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5==5.13

Using python 3.11.5 on Windows

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling.
I can use "pip install pyqt5" and it works to install version 5.15.2 but I need 5.13 or older for a package I'm trying to use. Any tips or is this just not possible any more?

Edit: Pip config list returns nothing. Also, if I directly try to install the .whl, I get this error: "PyQt5-5.13.0-5.13.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." I've tried the other whl files as well. Does this mean I need to downgrade my Python?

Comment: It's still on PyPI https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.13.0/ so maybe your index url is not pypi.  What does `pip conifg list` say? (edit output into the question)

Comment: What specific version of Python 3 are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: @wim updated the question with what you requested. Only led to more questions lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the wheels available at https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.13.0/ are compatible with your runtime (Python 3.11.5 on Windows), and they have not provided a source distribution on PyPI.

You can attempt to build PyQt5 from source code directly (get from https://github.com/PyQt5), but there are no guarantees that building this older version of PyQt5 for the recent Python version will succeed. It's likely that the changes in Python 3.11 required corresponding code changes in PyQt5 which is why you're only seeing 5.14.0+ versions available to pip.

Or you can try to find a wheel which is compatible with your runtime. Run the following command to display a list of wheel tags that your system is compatible with:

```
pip debug -v
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks. I ended up building the other library (that depended on the older version of PyQt) without the dependency. Thanks for your help.